# What's the relationship between profunctors and arrows?

Tags: haskell, functor, category-theory, arrows, profunctor

Apparently, every `Arrow` is a [`Strong`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/profunctors-4.3.2/docs/Data-Profunctor.html#t:Strong) profunctor. Indeed [`^>>`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Control-Arrow.html#v:-94--62--62-) and `>>^` correspond to `lmap` and `rmap`. And `first'` and `second'` are just the same as `first` and `second`. Similarly every `ArrowChoice` is also [`Choice`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/profunctors-4.3.2/docs/Data-Profunctor.html#t:Choice).

What profunctors lack compared to arrows is the ability to compose them. If we add composition, will we get an arrow? In other words, if a (strong) profunctor is also a [category](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Control-Category.html#t:Category), is it already an arrow? If not, what's missing?

Comment: [Kmett says](https://github.com/purescript-deprecated/purescript-arrows/issues/9) Arrow is precisely Strong Category.

Comment: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/profunctors-5.2/docs/Data-Profunctor-Composition.html ?

Comment: Linked in the [Profunctors in Haskell](http://blog.sigfpe.com/2011/07/profunctors-in-haskell.html): [Categorifying Computations into Components via Arrows as Profunctors](http://www-mmm.is.s.u-tokyo.ac.jp/~ichiro/papers/fromComptoComp.pdf).

Answer (score 39, accepted):

> What profunctors lack compared to arrows is the ability to compose them. If we add composition, will we get an arrow?

### MONOIDS

This is exactly the question tackled in section 6 of "[Notions of Computation as Monoids](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1406.4823.pdf)," which unpacks a result from the (rather dense) "[Categorical semantics for arrows](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/cheunen/publications/2008/arrows/arrows.pdf)". "Notions" is a great paper because while it dives deep into category theory it (1) doesn't assume the reader has more than a cursory knowledge of abstract algebra and (2) illustrates most of the migraine-inducing mathematics with Haskell code. We can briefly summarize section 6 of the paper here:

Say we have

```
class Profunctor p where
  dimap :: (contra' -> contra) -> (co -> co') -> p contra co -> p contra' co'
```

Your bog-standard, negative-and-positive dividin' encoding of profunctors in Haskell. Now this data type,

```
data (⊗) f g contra co = forall x. (f contra x) ⊗ (g x co)
```

as implemented in [Data.Profunctor.Composition](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/profunctors-5.2/docs/Data-Profunctor-Composition.html), acts like composition for profunctor. We can, for example, demonstrate a lawful instance `Profunctor`:

```
instance (Profunctor f, Profunctor g) => Profunctor (f ⊗ g) where
  dimap contra co (f ⊗ g) = (dimap contra id f) ⊗ (dimap id co g)
```

We will hand-wave the proof that it is lawful for reasons of time and space.

OK. Now the fun part. Say we this typeclass:

```
class Profunctor p => ProfunctorMonoid p where
  e :: (a -> b) -> p a b
  m :: (p ⊗ p) a b -> p a b
```

This is, with a lot more hand-waving, a way of encoding the notion of profunctor monoids in Haskell. Specifically this is a monoid in the monoidal category `Pro`, which is a monoidal structure for the functor category `[C^op x C, Set]` with `⊗` as the tensor and `Hom` as its unit. So there's a lot of ultraspecific mathematical diction to unpack here but for that you should just read the paper.

We then see that `ProfunctorMonoid` is isomorphic to `Arrow` ... almost.

```
instance ProfunctorMonoid p => Category p where
  id = dimap id id
  (.) pbc pab = m (pab ⊗ pbc)

instance ProfunctorMonoid p => Arrow p where
  arr = e
  first = undefined

instance Arrow p => Profunctor p where
  lmap = (^>>)
  rmap = (>>^)

instance Arrow p => ProfunctorMonoid p where
  e = arr
  m (pax ⊗ pxb) = pax >> pxb
```

Of course we are ignoring the typeclass laws here but, as the paper shows, they do work out fantastically.

Now I said almost because crucially we were unable to implement `first`. What we have really done is demonstrated an isomorphism between `ProfunctorMonoid` and *pre-arrows* .The paper calls `Arrow` without `first` a *pre-arrow*. It then goes on to show that

```
class Profunctor p => StrongProfunctor p where
  first :: p x y -> p (x, z) (y, z)

class StrongProfunctor p => StrongProfunctorMonoid p where
  e :: (a -> b) -> p a b
  m :: (p ⊗ p) a b -> p a b
```

is necessary and sufficient for the desired isomorphism to `Arrow`. The word "strong" comes from a specific notion in category theory and is described by the paper in better writing and richer detail than I could ever muster.

So to summarize:

- A monoid in the category of profunctors is a pre-arrow, and vice versa. (A previous version of the paper used the term "weak arrows" instead of pre-arrows, and that's OK too I guess.)
- A monoid in the category of strong profunctors is an arrow, and vice versa.
- Since monad is a monoid in the category of endofunctors we can think of the SAT analogy `Functor : Profunctor :: Monad : Arrow`. This is the real thrust of the notions-of-computation-as-monoids paper.
- Monoids and monoidal categories are gentle sea creatures that appear everywhere, and it's a shame that some students will go through computer science or software engineering education without being taught monoids.
- Category theory is fun.
- Haskell is fun.

Answer (score 7):

@haoformayor's answer (and the referenced paper) is a great insight into the underlying category theory - monoidal categories are rather beautiful! - but I thought some code showing you how to turn an `Arrow` into a `Strong Category` and vice versa as they appear in their respective libraries might make a helpful addendum.

```
import Control.Arrow
import Control.Category
import Data.Profunctor
import Data.Profunctor.Strong
import Prelude hiding (id, (.))
```

One way...

```
newtype WrapP p a b = WrapP { unwrapP :: p a b }

instance Category p => Category (WrapP p) where
    id = WrapP id
    WrapP p . WrapP q = WrapP (p . q)

instance (Category p, Strong p) => Arrow (WrapP p) where
    first = WrapP . first' . unwrapP
    second = WrapP . second' . unwrapP

    -- NB. the first usage of id comes from (->)'s Category instance (id :: a -> a)
    -- but the second uses p's instance (id :: p a a)
    arr f = WrapP $ dimap f id id
```

... and t'other...

```
newtype WrapA p a b = WrapA { unwrapA :: p a b }

instance Arrow p => Profunctor (WrapA p) where
    dimap f g p = WrapA $ arr f >>> unwrapA p >>> arr g

instance Arrow p => Strong (WrapA p) where
    first' = WrapA . first . unwrapA
    second' = WrapA . second . unwrapA
```

Comment: With that `dimap f id id` piece you've opened my eyes. Finally I realize how `Strong` and `Category` are sufficient for `Arrow`! :) Thanks

Comment: `dimap id f id`, yes.