# Bifunctor vs. Arrow methods

Tags: haskell, typeclass, arrows, bifunctor

There is a bit of overlap between `Bifunctor` and `Arrow` methods:

```
class Bifunctor p where
  first :: (a -> a') -> p a b -> p a' b
  second :: (b -> b') -> p a b -> p a b'
  bimap :: (a -> a') -> (b -> b') -> p a b -> p a' b'

class Arrow (~~>) where
  ...
  first :: (a ~~> a') -> (a, b) ~~> (a', b)
  second :: (b ~~> b') -> (a, b) ~~> (a, b')
  (***) :: (a ~~> a') -> (b ~~> b') -> (a, b) ~~> (a', b')
```

The `Bifunctor` class comes with laws completely analogous to those of `Functor`.

The `Arrow` class comes with a number of laws different laws and a somewhat cryptic warning about `(***)`: "Note that this is in general not a functor." Surprisingly (to me) there's only one law about `(***)`:

```
first f >>> arr (id *** g) = arr (id *** g) >>> first f
```

The `Arrow (->)` instance and the `Bifunctor (,)` instance match up exactly, so that `bimap @(,) = (***) @(->)`. Is there some special significance to this? Is there a meaningful hypothetical

```
class Foo (~~>) p where
  biFoo :: (a ~~> a') -> (b ~~> b') -> p a b ~~> p a' b'
```

If so, does that admit functional dependencies?

Comment: read about Profunctor

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Arrow` is a (somewhat bastardized) precursor to a class of [cartesian closed categories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_closed_category), or a least [cartesian monoidal categories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_monoidal_category). Specifically, to monoidal categories whose tensor product is `(,)` and unit element `()`.

Recall that a [monoidal category](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoidal_category) is characterised by the tensor product as a bifunctor, so there's your connection between `Arrow` and `Bifunctor`.

`***` has in fact more laws than you listed, only, the library chooses to formulate those in terms of `first` instead. Here's an equivalent definition of the class:

```
class (Category k, Category k') => EnhancedCategory k k' where
  arr :: k a b -> k' a b
  -- arr id ≡ id
  -- arr (f . g) = arr f . arr g
class (EnhancedCategory (->) a) => Arrow a where
  (***) :: a b c -> a b' c' -> a (b,b') (c,c')
  -- (f***id) . (g***id) ≡ (f.g)***id
  -- (id***f) . (id***g) ≡ id***(f.g)
  -- arr fst . (f***id) ≡ f . arr fst
  -- arr snd . (id***g) ≡ g . arr snd
  -- ¿ arr swap . (f***g) ≡ (g***f) . arr swap ?
  -- ((f***g)***h) . assoc ≡ assoc . (f***(g***h))
  diag :: a b (b,b)

first :: Arrow a => a b c -> a (b,d) (c,d)
first f = f***id
second :: Arrow a => a b c -> a (d,b) (d,c)
second g = id***g
(&&&) :: Arrow a => a b c -> a b d -> a b (c,d)
f&&&g = (f***g) . diag
```

Incidentally, it is also possible to remove the `arr` for lifting pure functions, and instead give the superclass only the dedicated methods `fst`, `snd` and `assoc`. [I call that class `Cartesian`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/constrained-categories-0.4.0.0/docs/Control-Category-Constrained.html#t:Cartesian). This allows defining “arrow” categories that *don't* contain arbitrary Haskell functions; [linear maps](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/linearmap-category-0.3.5.0/docs/Math-LinearMap-Category.html#g:3) are an important example.

Comment: There's lots I don't understand yet, but let me start by asking what `EnhancedCategory` is.

Comment: `class EnhancedCategory k k' where arr :: k a b -> k' a b`. Actually I'm not sure if the term is established or I made it up new [in `constrained-categories`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/constrained-categories-0.4.0.0/docs/Control-Arrow-Constrained.html#t:EnhancedCat). — Edited that into answer.

Comment: `arr fst . (f***g) ≡ f . arr fst` that (and the two after it) doesn't seem right for the `Kleisli m` arrow instance.

Comment: Hm, you're right; this actually seems specific to `f***id` (i.e., to `first f`). Also, not sure about the swap law...

Comment: So I guess there *could* be a `MonoidalCategory` class with an explicit tensor product. But no fundeps?

Comment: You mean, like http://hackage.haskell.org/package/categories-1.0.7/docs/Control-Category-Cartesian.html ?

Comment: Is `EnhancedCategory` not just a different name for `Functor` (generalised to non-**Hask**)?

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson yeah, it's kind of “two categories with one canonical functor between them”. If there's a name for that in maths, I'd like to know. `Functor` at any rate can't be used for that class...

Answer (score 1):

`Arrow` is [equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38169453/1523776) to [`Strong`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/profunctors-5.4/docs/Data-Profunctor-Strong.html#t:Strong) + [`Category`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Control-Category.html#t:Category).

You can choose [a different notion of strength](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/profunctors-5.4/docs/Data-Profunctor-Choice.html#t:Choice) to get [a different kind of `Arrow`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Control-Arrow.html#t:ArrowChoice).

```
class Category a => ArrowChoice a where
    arr :: (b -> c) -> a b c
    (+++) :: a b c -> a b' c' -> a (Either b b') (Either c c')
```

In other words, the tensor product of your Cartesian closed category needn't be `(,)` exactly. Any tensor product you can come up with has a corresponding notion of strength, each of which would give you a corresponding variety of `Arrow`.

Notably, many profunctors are both `Strong` and `Choice`, so your `Foo` (which basically generalises `Strong` over a tensor product `p`) doesn't have a functional dependency.

The `Control.Arrow` module in `base` unfortunately muddles the hierarchy together a little bit (for example, their `ArrowChoice` has `Arrow` as a superclass).